# How to create hybrid apps with native look and feel

Tags: gwt, web-applications, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, mgwt

## Short version:

Basically I have two questions highlighted below. However, my original question is based on some research, that's why the text below is a little bit longer. Here is what I would like to know:

1. Would you have any recommendations which frameworks I could use for building hybrid apps with native look and feel without using a cloud service for compilation?
2. Which libraries could you recommend to get native look and feel?

**Please do only post open-source solutions.**

## Original question:

I like to build an app for multiple mobile platforms such as *Android, iOS, Blackberry and Windows Phone 8* using the idea of *hybrid apps* (or at least web apps). Since I already made some research on existing frameworks, I was wondering if there are any frameworks not compiling my app in a cloud?
The company I work for would not be able send source code to a cloud service which builds the app, e.g. cloud compiling platforms like the [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine), [Phonegab](http://phonegap.com/) or the [Intel App Framework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/) (formerly jQmobi) *[please, correct me if I'm wrong with that]*.

Furthermore, the apps should look and feel native on all devices (at least default elements such as navigation button, list views, buttons, edit text fields and so on..). A few month ago, I discovered the combination of [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) + [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) + [gwt-Phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/) + [m-gwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) to build native looking hybrid apps (extendable by phonegap plugins to allow native functions). First of all, it looked great to me. But, AFAIK, Phonegap will always compile apps remotely in a cloud, since Adobe is providing all the build infrastructure, right?

**Would you have any recommendations which frameworks I could use for building hybrid apps with native look and feel without using a cloud service for compilation?**

Just an idea: Since Phonegap is based on [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), which compiles locally on my own build infrastructure, I was wondering if anybody of you experienced to create apps using Cordova + some library to create native look and feel (m-gwt seems not being updated anymore). **Which libraries could you recommend to get native look and feel?**

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: PhoneGap and Cordova are interchange-able, You can build both locally on your machine using their clients. You can install those using npm, `npm install -g cordova` and/or `npm install -g phonegap`. With either the UI is completely up to you, so you can make it look as native as you would like.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Thanks for your reply. I have not experienced Phonegap, yet. Would you have any recommendations on libraries for native look and feel? I discovered jQuerymobile, which seems to be updated. However, it looks more like "plain" web app look and feel, not native.

Comment: Take a look at Ionic. `http://ionicframework.com/` They seem to be the best right now, or if you just want UI, try topcoat `http://topcoat.io/`

Comment: You can take a look at the DevExtreme (https://www.devexpress.com/Products/HTML-JS/). It uses the PhoneJS native look and feel applications JavaScript framework (http://phonejs.devexpress.com/). Finally DevExpress DevExtreme creates a native package (in the PhoneGap container) using MS Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using mgwt and gwt phonegap in our applications, both started by Daniel. And we are ok with mgwt performance. Yes, there have been no releases on mgwt and gwt phonegap recently. But Daniel is working on a new version of mgwt, although I don't know exactly when it will be released. But the updates have recently been merged with the master on github, so I am expecting a release soon. Similarly with gwt phonegap there is no release for almost a year now and it is behind phonegap by at least 10 versions. I am working on the upgrade to the latest version, all the API's except the File API are completed and are committed to master on github.

The new version of mgwt have significant improvements like a standard theme, L & F for iOS 7 and support for new platforms. mgwt is still not out :)

Comment: That's great news. I need to check out the master. You mean [this one for MGWT](https://github.com/dankurka/mgwt) and [that one for gwtPhonegap](https://github.com/dankurka/gwtphonegap), right?

Comment: Yes, the links are in progress. But please note that they are work in progress, so just don't panic if you find some thing wrong. Please report the bugs or your observations. I can fix the bugs on gwt Phonegap.